# Accessing Outlook 2013 from Internet

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook-web-access

I'm using my own computer to manage email at home. When I'm out, I get access to my Outlook from Internet by using Remote Desktop Connection. This works very well.

Is there any other way to get access to my emails in Outlook from Internet? Does Outlook have some Web interface to expose itself on the Web?

Could I connect another Web interface to Outlook in order to not use RDP?

Comment: Outlook does not; Exchange does.

Comment: I read that Exchange has the Outlook Web Access. Is it possible to install it on a desktop computer?

Comment: **OWA is Exchange**

Answer (score 0):

To answer a question with a question.  What mailserver are you using? and is it set up as IMAP or POP3?

The basic difference is, POP3 is the older of the 2 protocols and was designed when devices where expensive and internet connections were dialup.  The concept behind POP3 is that the client (outlook) retrieves the mail and deletes it from the server. (there is also a not very useful setting that leave the mail on the server).  At the time, people had one computer, and it was dialup, they got their mail and went back offline.  Not very good for managing mail across multiple devices like we all have today.

Enter IMAP into the picture.  (a quick note for those scared of IMAP--10-15 years ago your fears were justifiable--it didn't work very well--it does in 2014.)  IMAP is designed to maintain your email folders on the server.  When Outlook connects it synchs your local folder with those one the server.  The nice thing here is OTHER devices of yours can also connect and synch those folders.  Your outlook, your phone, your tablet, and lastly a special category webmail.   Your email provider will provide you with a webmail address usually.  You can go to that address in any browser and read/reply/file etc.

So if are using IMAP or can change to it, chances are you can use webmail to log into your mail account when away.

Since Exchange is mentioned in a comment, it's worth mention that Exchange is a Microsoft server product based on IMAP, but it's more like IMAP on steroids.  Exchange provides many additional features as well as a portable version of Outlook in the form of webmail.  Exchange and Outlook are created by Microsoft to work incredibly well together.  But you do not have to have an Exchange server to use outlook.

Comment: I'm using numerous mail servers has I manage multiple differents accounts in Outlook. This is why I would like to use Outlook has an entry point to read my mails. (And I prefer using Outlook rather than a "cloud" Webmail.)

Comment: What you probably want then is an Exchange account. Mail can be collected from multiple other accounts and webmail is know as Outlook Web Access or OWA.  Don't be confused by the name, it's not web access for YOUR copy of outlook, it's a webmail interface that is outlook like.